# Get all childrens of a specific parent category PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[Database Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMZXr.png)

Hello, Please see the uploaded Image,

My question is how to get all the children categories id with a specific parent category id in PHP.

Like:

- if we select category id 1, we get (1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
- if we select category id 2, we get (2, 7)
- if we select category id 3, we get (3)
- if we select category id 4, we get (4, 5, 6)
- if we select category id 7, we get (7)

Comment: I don't see anything that shows category_id. It would be just a hard guess for now.

Comment: id is the category_id in the table

Comment: I still don't see the full relation, but let's start with this.... `select * from sometable a where a.parent_id = (select b.parent_id from sometable b where b.id = $id);`

Comment: What if i want to make it a loop? means do this internal queries until parent id is finished

Comment: I think the better option is the recursion, but I am still complicated in doing that

Answer (score 0):

Here is query to get parent and all descendant categories using recursion

```
WITH RECURSIVE categorie AS (
SELECT id,
    name,
    parent_id,
    status,
    ordering
FROM table_name
WHERE parent_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT child.id,
    child.name,
    child.parent_id,
    child.status,
    child.ordering
FROM table_name child
JOIN categorie c
  ON c.id = child.parent_id
)

SELECT id, name, parent_id, status, ordering
FROM categorie;
```

Detail explanation can be found [here](https://learnsql.com/blog/query-parent-child-tree/)

You could also start from topmost category and look for children one level at time. That allows you to group results easier but executes more queries to db.

function to get all children would be something like this

```
public function getAllChildrenForParent($parent_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name where parent_id = :parent_id";
    
    //query db
    $result = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $result[] = $row;
        $result[]['children'] = $this->getAllChildrenForParent($row['id']);
    }
    return $result;
}
```